# VBA Count if empty/blank and output in the top row - loop columns array

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make a macro that will be summing the non blank in a column range (and I want it to loop in a column's array) and show the output in the top row (row 12).

I used this post [Sum range-loop in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678282/sum-range-loop-in-vba) but couldn't apply for my case.

So far I've done this:

```
Sub Count_blanks()
    Dim arrControlSheet As Variant
    Dim SumErrors As Integer
    Dim TtlErrors As Double
    Dim h As Long

    arrControlSheet = Array("D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L")

    For h = LBound(arrControlSheet) To UBound(arrControlSheet)
        With Sheets("Control")
            TtlErrors = Cells(12, arrControlSheet(h)) = Application.CountA(Range(Cells(13, arrControlSheet(h)), Cells(80, arrControlSheet(h))))
        .Range(arrControlSheet(h) & 12) = TtlErrors
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Please see the below screenshot to have better visualization:

[image: Screenshot1]

The macro is supposed to update the row 12, indicating the number of non-blank cells in that respective column (from row 13 to 80).

Thank you very much

Comment: Should it be `TtlErrors = Application.CountA(Range(Cells(13, arrControlSheet(h)), Cells(80, arrControlSheet(h))))`? You have two equals signs in that line.

Comment: You want a macro.  Why not formula =COUNTA(D13:D65536) ?  Just curious.

Comment: @dcromley thanks for the suggestion, for this case I wanted to use vba, but thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub CalculateNonBlank()
```

`Dim n As Integer`

`For i = 4 To 12`

`n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(14, i), Cells(Rows.Count, i)))
    Cells(12, i).Value = n`

`Next`

`End Sub`